# I'm trying to webscrape, but I'm failing at a loop. Using R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, rvest

everyone. I know this is stupid and I wouldn't be asking if I hadn't checked every single *for loop* answer here.

But I need to scrape 95 pages and I can't figure out how to loop it.

This is the code:

```
url <- "https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/Dokument-Lagar/?datum=2000-01-01&q=kvinn&st=2&tom=2018-12-31&doktyp=fr&p="

page <- read_html(url)
title_html <- html_nodes(page,'.medium-big')    
text_html <- html_nodes(page,'.font-bold')   
full_html <- html_nodes(page, '.medium-smaller')
text_html[[21]] <- NULL
full_html[c(1, 21, 22)] <- NULL
title <- html_text(title_html)
text <- html_text(text_html)
full <- html_text(full_html)
frame <- data.frame(title, text, full)
```

It gets me everything I need, except I need to go page by page. I'm using rvest and dplyr.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to loop through different URLs? Is that it? Just make a function that receives `url` as input and outputs `frame`, then `lapply` over the URL vector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are generalizing the url variable into a vector of string urls. If thats the case you can do something like the following

```r
urls <- c("url1", "url2", "url3")

myScrape <- function(url) {
   age <- read_html(url)
   title_html <- html_nodes(page,'.medium-big')    
   text_html <- html_nodes(page,'.font-bold')   
   full_html <- html_nodes(page, '.medium-smaller')
   text_html[[21]] <- NULL
   full_html[c(1, 21, 22)] <- NULL
   title <- html_text(title_html)
   text <- html_text(text_html)
   full <- html_text(full_html)
   data.frame(title, text, full) 
}

all_pages <- lapply(urls, myScrape)
```

You are going to need to play with the code to get it into the format you want (e.g. a list of data frames is generally not useful) but the script now loops!

Comment: You can use the `dplyr::bind_rows(all_pages)` to merge everything into 1 final data.frame if desired.  Here is a similar question/answer.

Comment: I really appreciate this (even though I haven't managed to get it to work...)!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it like this, but I think your code has a problem regarding the last full_html information of each page:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/Dokument-Lagar/?datum=2000-01-01&q=kvinn&st=2&tom=2018-12-31&doktyp=fr&p="

data <- NULL
for (i in 1:95){
  page <- read_html(paste0(url, i))
  title_html <- html_nodes(page,'.medium-big')    
  text_html <- html_nodes(page,'.font-bold')   
  full_html <- html_nodes(page, '.medium-smaller')
  text_html[[21]] <- NULL
  full_html[c(1, 21, 22)] <- NULL
  title <- html_text(title_html)
  text <- html_text(text_html)
  full <- html_text(full_html)
  frame <- data.frame(title, text, full) 
  data <- rbind(data, frame)
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! It's exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you so much! (Yes, I see the missing line from full, I'm gonna check the page to see where it is).